# Prevent Matlab from creating java.log.* files in the home directory?

Tags: linux, java, matlab

I've recently started using matlab.  If started with the jvm, log files will be created in the home directory (a different one every time it starts up).

`Opening log file:  /home/max/java.log.4363`

The number at the end is different every time.  Is there anyway I can change the location of this file (say a temporary directory)?

I can see no such option in `matlab -help`.

I should mention that I am currently using matlab 2015, but the same occurs with other recent-ish versions.

Answer (score 1):

As written in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37705023) by [Suever](https://stackoverflow.com/users/670206/suever) to a similar question, you need to specify the `MATLAB_LOG_DIR` environment variable before starting matlab.

Comment: It's better to make answers self-contained by including the essential information within it.  Use the link for attribution and reference.  Posting just a link to someone else's answer is more appropriate as a comment.

Comment: I just didn't want to simply copy the answer as there was nothing to add to it in my opinion.
I also thought that an answer would be more visible than the comment.
Thanks for pointing that out though, next time I'll just comment